# What are the effects of an empty group, {}?

Tags: grouping, parsing

In order to have a syntactic space after a no-argument command, one is taught to delimit the command token with an empty group (`{}`), like this: `\somecommand{} more LaTeX material`.

However an empty group isn't without meaning: in math mode, `\({} + a\)` is typeset differently from `\( + a\)`.

Also, `\(\somecommand{} + a\)` and `\(\somecommand + a\)` are interestingly different. (Insert for example `\empty` or `\allowbreak` for `\somecommand` here.) (An explanatory note: Spaces don't matter in math mode, so since in `\(\somecommand + a\)` the `\somecommand` eats up the following space, I would have expected the two to yield identical results. An explanation for why these two are different is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98821/14996).)

This makes me wonder about what else one might need to pay attention to when using empty groups. **What are the effects of an empty group and where might one use one?**

Comment: May be this is somehow related: [What is the difference between \relax and {}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My understanding is that `{}` has no effect in printing (so long as it doesn't follow a macro with arguments). As `{` isn't a letter, the collecting of command name stops (a quirk of TeX is that if the collecting stops at whitespace, said whitespace is gobbled up). In math mode, if you write `$+ a$`, it is a plus *sign*, while in `$a + b$` it is a *binary addition symbol* (written the same, different meaning, different spacing). Writing `${} + a$` means nothing (an empty group) added to `$a$`, i.e., an addition.

Summary:

- In text, use `\somecommand{}` to stop (La)TeX from eating the following space, or `\somecommand{}moretext` to stop the command name timely (but perhaps `{\somecommand}` (if this is safe, meaning `\somecommand` does not perform an assignment) in both cases is clearer)
- In math, use it as a "nothing here, but pretend there was" term/factor in expressions to force interpretation/spacing as a binary operator.

Comment: "Expansion" in TeX has a technical meaning that doesn't apply here. More precisely, `{}` in text mode does (almost) nothing (if it's not the argument to a command). It might prevent automatic kerning if placed in the middle of a word, though.

Comment: @egreg, please edit my ramblings to fix any misunderstandings of wrong wording.

Comment: I think egreg's comment about kerning is important.  In such a case, one should use `\somecommand moretext` with nothing in between.

Comment: @egreg Can one really use `{\somecommand}` instead of `\somecommand` in all cases where `\somecommand` does not take arguments? Doesn't the grouping localize (i.e., locally limit) the scope of certain changes?

Comment: @LoverofStructure If `\somecommand` performs some assignment, it of course shouldn't be in braces. In most cases parameterless macros don't.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Wouldn't the existence of a command in the middle of a word prevent kerning already? Could you try to come up with a specific example?

Comment: @egreg I've accepted this answer after some editing, but I thought it might be useful to ping an expert just in case there is something I missed. (This comment can be deleted by anyone thinking that this answer is complete.)

Answer (score 18):

*This is in reply to the OP's question in the @vonbrand answer thread.*

In fact, an empty group in the middle of a word (but *not* just a command by itself) prevents kerning (special spacing between pairs of letters) and ligatures.  The effect on ligatures is the most visible.

```
\def\f{f}
ffi    % => ligature of ffi
f\f i  % => ligature of ffi
f\f{}i % => ligature of ff, then i.
\bye
```

Here, it is typographically better to simply leave a single space after the parameterless macro `\f`.  Admittedly, this is not a practical example, since no one in their right mind would define such a macro.

A more practical example, perhaps is for someone who defines macros for shorthands of words (don't do this), for instance `\c` for `constrain`, and then adds `s`, or `t`, or whatever missing letters for plural, verb, etc.  The computer modern font (default of TeX) has a little bit of kerning (space) between `n` and `t`.  In the first two cases, TeX's stomach sees `constraints` and `\c ts` as a word, and applies kerning as appropriate.  In the last case, the empty group in `\c{}ts` makes TeX's stomach see two words: `constrain` and `ts`, thus no kerning is applied between `n` and `t`.

```
\def\c{constrain}
\def\test#1#2{\setbox0\hbox{#2}\immediate\write16{#1: \the\wd0}}
\test{No shorthand}{This constrains $a$ to obey some constraints.}
\test{No braces}{This \c s $a$ to obey some \c ts.}
\test{Braces}{This \c{}s $a$ to obey some \c{}ts.}
\bye
```

This might not apply to LuaTeX.

Comment: I don't think it applies to XeLaTex either. I read somewhere that an empty group is not enough to stop OpenType ligatures in XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the existing information: In math mode, `{}` is also used [to affect horizontal subscript/superscript positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85369/14996) and [to subtly affect vertical subscript/superscript positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3229/14996).