# What is a good method for producing a unary plus/minus sign that always works?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

Say I have a macro that does *something* in math mode (say, change the mathalphabet). This macro, `\somecommand`, takes one argument. I might want use is like this, feeding an empty argument into it: `\(\somecommand{} +x\)`. I also want the plus sign before `x` to be a unary operator.

I find that whether a plus or minus sign is considered unary or binary is, while clear in theory, not always *obvious* upon first inspection:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\zeroArgCommand}{}
\newcommand{\oneArgCommand}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\(                    +x\) \\ % unary:  "+x"
\(\zeroArgCommand     +x\) \\ % unary:  "+x"
\(\zeroArgCommand{}   +x\) \\ % binary: " + x"
\(\oneArgCommand{}    +x\) \\ % unary:  "+x"
\(\oneArgCommand{}{}  +x\) \\ % binary: " + x"

\end{document}
```

In the light of this, I am wondering about the **best way of defining a unary plus/minus sign**.

Intuitively I would write `\(\somecommand{} {+} x\)` or `\(\somecommand{} {+ x}\)`, but I am wondering about expert opinion about a method that for sure works in all contexts.

*This question was posed because in another thread, a user suggested that defining a `\unaryplus` macro is clearer than `\somecommand {+} x`. (I think what that commenter had in mind was that the reader might not be familiar with the arity of `\somecommand`.)*

---

**Addendum:** Is there a good way to define a macro `\genuineunaryplus` that produces a `+` but that in a context `<before>\genuineunaryplus<after>` attaches to `<after>` as a unary operator but has spacing to `<before>` exactly as if the `\genuineunaryplus` were not there? That is, a macro such that if the spacing between `<B> <A>` is of length/type L, the expression `<B>\genuineunaryplus<A>` will produce `<B> +<A>` in the output, with the spacing between `<B>` and `+` exactly like the spacing would be between `<B>` and `<A>` if the `\genuineunaryplus` were not there, namely L?

**Answer idea for addendum:** David Carlisle's [comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98815/what-is-a-good-method-for-producing-a-unary-plus-minus-sign-that-always-works/98821?noredirect=1#comment259865_98821) outlines a possible answer for this addendum.

Comment: Surprisingly, the output is as expected...

Comment: @Werner See my edit, giving a rationale for the question.

Comment: Why not just use `\unaryplus x` where `\newcommand{\unaryplus}{{+}}`?

Comment: @Werner See my new comments in the thread to David Carlisle's answer.

Comment: Again, this is too generic a question. TeX has no concept of "unary operator" in your sense; just an ordinary symbol will do, so `\mathord{+}` would be the answer, maybe buried in a macro. Using the same symbol for two different purposes is, in general, wrong. If your `+` has always to behave as unary, then use a different name for it.

Comment: @egreg I certainly didn't mean to redefine `+` as `\mathord{+}`; there might be a misunderstanding, but then my question's motivation wasn't completely clear, though I think the edit (in italics at the bottom) should have cleared that up (it was to give a better outlet for David Carlisle's comment elsewhere, which might have been deleted by now; he suggested that a separate question might be better). Anyways, see also my addendum; I think this is what I actually want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inspection of the math list happens *after* expansion (and after assignments). It is an extra stage just applicable to math mode that converts the math list into a horizontal list that is then typeset as a normal horizontal list.

So there is no real connection between the macro structure and the math spacing, It does not matter whether the thing to the left of the `+` has arguments or not, it just matters what it expands to (nothing in your example) so your example is equivalent to

```
\noindent
\(                    +x\) \\ % unary:  "+x"
\(     +x\) \\ % unary:  "+x"
\({}   +x\) \\ % binary: " + x"
\(    +x\) \\ % unary:  "+x"
\({}  +x\) \\ % binary: " + x"
```

and as your comments show a binop like `+` gets binary spacing if it is between two mathord atoms such as `{}` or `x`.

Your example (from elsewhere, with `\somecommand` being a zero-argument macro)

```
\(\somecommand{} {+} x\)
```

is

```
\({} {+} x\)
```

Here the `{+}` construct makes a mathord so you get no spacing. My comment that this was probably bad markup was mainly related to the trailing `{}` after `\somecommand` it is OK to do that habitually in text mode to avoid dropping spaces but in math mode it's usually has an effect.

```
\(\somecommand{} {+ x}\)
```

is

```
\({} {+ x}\)
```

so here the math list has two, not three, mathord atoms: `{}` and `+x`. In this simple case it doesn't affect the spacing, but the inner expression is a single atom, so `{+x}` (and not `x`) would take any superscripts etc, and as it is an inner list linebreaking is suppressed and any white space is forced to its natural width (again not relevant here); basically in math node `{...}` is a box command like `\hbox{....}`.

There are in fact two choices for a unary math sign, a mathord or a mathop, it's easy to get an ad hoc mathord by using `{+}` but it is probably more consistent to declare the operators explicitly.

[image]

```
1 $a-+b$

2 $a-{+}b$

3 $a-\mathord{+}b$

4 $a-\mathop{+}b$

5 $x+y$

6 $x{+}y$

7 $x\mathord{+}y$

8 $x\mathop{+}y$
```

As you see from (1) if two binop atoms are adjacent the second one effectively turns into a mathord so you get the spacing as in (2) or (3) although arguably as a prefix operator giving it mathop spacing (with a small gap before its argument) is more consistent.

either way you don't want to be filling you document expressions with weird `{}` constructs and `\mathxx` primitives, just define

```
\unaryplus{{+}}
```

or whatever version you like and then use

```
a + \unaryplus b
```

and it will all work out OK.

Comment: What if I would like to juxtapose `x` and `+y`, like so: `x +y`? Not sure whether this is useful for ordinary math, but it might be if `x` and `y` are more complicated symbols/expressions and I am using some special, domain-specific notation. Is there a macro definition that will always work?

Comment: Just now I realize that this isn't really a matter of creating a unary plus symbol, as I'd like relational spacing on the left and no spacing on the right. As this is what *also* motivated my question, I'll leave this comment as is, perhaps someone has a good idea that's different from the ad-hoc `\(x\;{+}y\)`, which feels like a hack to me.

Comment: @LoverofStructure If you feel that a thick space should go after `x`, then `\(\mathrel{x}+y\)` will do what you want.

Comment: `\;{x}` isn't  a bad thing necessarily just don't use it mid document call that `\unaryplus` (or whatever name you want) and let your document markup concentrate on the structure and you can fine tune spacing at the end (you may decide `\;` (thickmuskip) is a bit much and you want medmuskip or whatever, it is easy to change a single definition.

Comment: You mean `\;{+}`. You've turned the `x` by 45° :-)

Comment: er yes:-)​​​​​​

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Btw see also my addendum to the question. (Sorry for keeping everyone here so busy ... but while I'm at it, I might as well be precise and clear stuff up and help create a complete question/answer pair.)

Comment: answer to addendum is "yes" but that's all you get at this time of night you need to rip apart the code of `bm` package that works out what type of atom each thing is, the instead of reconstructing a bold version of the same you'd just insert a `+` can be simpler as it only needs to find the first atom not iterate over a list  but it's surprisingly tricky (and even trickier if you want xetex or luatex) to work out the mathclass of mathchardefed tokens. 99 times out of 100 a unary plus is going to be applied to a mathord isn't it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. Is there an easy way to define this *under the assumption that the next token is a mathord*? That is, there is a dependence on the previous token's math character class only.

Comment: if the next token is a mathord then the space between B and + in B{+}A` is the same as the space between B and A in `BA`. So there is nothing to do in that case?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, because `{+}` is a mathord itself, you're right!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Btw, I occasionally miss your comments because they're not @-addressed to me. A question's OP currently doesn't get notifications to comments to answers to his questions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Now that my question about mixed math character classes has [an ingenious answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111881/14996), is there now an easy way to answer my "Addendum" (see bottom of the original question statement here)? If so, I'm very glad to write a separate question about this.

Comment: @LoverofStructure you could recycle `bm` code which looks up the mathclass of the thing following the + but it's a lot of work for little gain, and still falls foul if you do bad markup like `\zeroArgCommand{}` which introduces spurious mathord atom from the `{}`