# Negative logarithm: spacing

Tags: equations

The equation `$\max - \log x$` renders in a weird way:

[image: equation]

The minus is a unary operator (i.e. it means "negative logarithm", and not "the difference between max and log"). So I would expect that it would be closer to "log". That happens for `$-b$` as opposed to `$a-b$`:

[image]

Is there a better way than `$-\log x$` to write the negative logarithm?

Comment: I'd use `\max(-\log x)`

Comment: What if I don't want to write the parentheses? I'm concerned about the spacing in `$\max -\log x$` as opposed to `$\max -b$`.

Comment: I consider very ambiguous even `\max\log x`, because there's no binding of the variable. I can suggest `\max-{\log x}`,

Comment: It's actually `\max\{\log x:x>0\}` (or whatever interval you compute the maximum over.

Comment: What about `\max{}-\log x`? I dislike, but...

Comment: I'm equally concerned about the spacing of the minus in `$$\max_{x\in X} -\log x$$`. @egreg is that what you mean by binding?

Comment: @Sigur that renders in the same way

Comment: @root, are you sure? Try `\[ \max-\log x \]\[ \max{}-\log x \]`. https://imgur.com/a/1MCHvT7

Comment: @Sigur in the Online LaTeX Equation Editor, it looks the same http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cmax-%5Clog%20x http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cmax%7B%7D-%5Clog%20x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @egreg pointed out in the comments, to avoid ambiguity a pair of parentheses is **recommended**. Or maybe you could try `$\max_{x\ge2} -{\log x}$` instead of the full expression `$\max\{ \, -{\log x} : x\ge2 \, \}$`.

You mentioned you wanted a **unary negation**, so you *have* to use `$-{\log x}$`, and even `$-\log x$` is *incorrect*.

In the `$-\log x$` example, `\log` is of class `\mathop`, and the minus sign (which is not a binary operation here) will be rendered as an ordinary object (class `\mathord` - see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/164314) to learn about math classes). And so a thin space `\,` is added between them (because a thin space is always inserted between `\mathord` and `\mathop` - see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111757/164314) - think `$\sin x\cos x$` for example).

Therefore, to truly get unary negation, you must make sure whatever you are negating is itself an ordinary object. This can be done by simply enclosing `\log x` within a pair of `{}`. Same idea applies to `$-{\sin x}$`, `$\tan x = {\sin x}/{\cos x}$`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! What's ambiguous about `$\max\log x$` without parentheses, what else can it mean apart from `$\max(\log x)$`? Why does `$-\log$` create an "impossible" combination, where is it explained that `$-` cannot be followed by a `\mathop`?

Comment: @root A `-` in math mode is classified as `\mathbin` by default. “Impossible” means “it is impossible to start math mode with a `\mathbin`”, hence the `\mathord` adjustment. A `\mathop` _can_ follow a `\mathord`—see my mentioned example. You can check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/164314) to learn about math classes, and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111757/164314) for the spacing rules.

Comment: @root done! `:)`

Comment: Thanks `:)` In the `$-\log x$` example and the `$\max-\log x$` example

Comment: @root not quite. In `$\max-\log x$`, the minus sign is a perfectly normal binary, the atoms in this math list are `mathop mathbin mathop mathord`.

Answer (score 4):

A double pair of braces will do the trick. However, I also prefer to add a pair of parentheses:

```
\documentclas{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
     & \smashoperator{\max_{1 < x < \mathrm e}}{-}{\log x}\\
 & \smashoperator{\max_{1 < x < \mathrm e}} ({-}{\log x})
    \end{align*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]