# Double subscript with \bar

Tags: subscripts

When I used this code:

```
$ {\bar{a}_x}_y $
```

MiKtex said:

```
Double subscript $ {\bar{a}_x}_
```

How to fix?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Double superscript error involving tilde](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32739) and [Weird relative positioning of superscript and subscript with \dot, \bar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85365)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use either of the following options:

```
$\bar{a}{{}_x}_y$
$\bar{a}_{xy}$
${\bar{a}}_{x_y}$
```

Here's the difference in output:

[image]