# Why doesn't \mathord work to turn an Acc atom into Ord?

Tags: math-mode, errors, tex-core, superscripts

Writing `${\dot X^a}^b$` produces a very cryptic "double superscript" error: this has been explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32739/double-superscript-error-involving-tilde) on this forum: the reason is that `{\dot X}^a` generates an Acc atom and that, for a reason that only Knuth must know, putting braces around a single Acc atom does not work to turn it into an Ord nucleus like it does for *any other* math list (see page 291, ¶5, of the TeXbook, quoted in the aforementioned thread).

What I'd like to know, now, is why `$\mathord{\dot X^a}^b$` (or, for that matter, `${\mathord{\dot X}^a}^b$`) doesn't work any better: unlike simple grouping, `\mathord` is not supposed to have any weird exception for single Acc atoms, at least if I believe the TeXbook (just two paragraphs below).

It's simple enough to work around (`$\mathord{{}\dot X^a}^b$` works, or simply `${{}\dot X^a}^b$`), and of course one shouldn't be writing this sort of thing anyway, but what I'd like to know is: does this count as a bug in TeX?  Do I win a $327.68 check from Knuth ;-), or is there some fine print somewhere in the TeXbook or elsewhere that explains how `\mathord` is supposed to work?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The `\dot` accent produces an Ord atom anyway …?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I'm merely trying to understand what's going on within the bizarre internals of TeX.  And no, `\dot` really seems to produce an Acc atom (why do you think it would be Ord?).

Comment: Let me clarify: `\dot` is an “Acc” atom. `\dot` makes `\dot X` an Ord atom. TeXbook: “Other kinds of atoms, which arise from
commands like […] `\mathaccent` […], are all treated as type Ord […]” (p. 170).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: It's still an Acc atom, it's only _treated_ like an Ord in horizontal spacing.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: The fine print on p.290 might be relevant, where it is explained what a `<math field>` is.

Comment: I'm afraid you have discovered that `\mathord{<math>}` is *exactly* the same as `{<math>}`. See also module 1186 in `tex.web` where the "brace removing" around an Acc atom is described.

Comment: @egreg that looks like an answer to me:-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you have discovered that `\mathord{<math>}` is exactly the same as `{<math>}`. See also module 1186 in `tex.web` where the "brace removing" around an Acc atom is described:

> **1186** Now at last we’re ready to see what happens when a right brace occurs in a math formula. Two special cases are simplified here: Braces are effectively removed when they surround a single Ord without sub/superscripts, or when they surround an accent that is the nucleus of an Ord atom.