# Enclosing symbols in braces to reduce space around them

Tags: math-mode, spacing, braces

Why does enclosing a symbol in in curly braces e.g. `{\in}` suppress space around the symbol? I cannot seem to locate any documentation which explains this behavior, or describes which symbols it applies to. Any clarification or references would be much appreciated.

[image: example]

Comment: Enclosing in braces makes a `\mathord` atom, with the corresponding spacing rules (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/82917)).

Comment: I can't find a similar question, though I think there should be one (the issue pops out every once in a while). [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105776/82917) is the closest thing I found out. Anyway it's documented in the TeXBook, see the end of the quote from the TeXBook in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/82917).