# Double superscript error while typing equations

Tags: superscripts

When I try to write

```
\begin{equation}
{\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger}}^{2}
\end{equation}
```

I am getting this error

```
! Double superscript.
l.4 {\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger}}^
                            {2}
?
```

So what is the proper way of writing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger 2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Possibly `\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger\,2}` if you want a little bit more space before between the symbols in the superscript.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite surprising, given that

```
${a^b}^c$
```

works and

```
${\hat{a}^b}^c$
```

not. Look for a complete analyisis at [Double superscript error involving tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32739/double-superscript-error-involving-tilde) (which is the same problem).

The problem is that there is a doubt between the position of the hat and the exponents.

Is the two a superscript of what? The `\hat{a}`? The `a` (and so it should go with the hat, same level)? The whole `a_1^\dagger`? Depending on the answer the formula will be different...

(Given your way of writing the equation, I suspect you where looking for the first one).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger}\right.^{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger 2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger^2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: three different case]

PD I will call this quite an "hidden feature" (!) of TeX math... first one I found in 20 years. Although it's known and planned this way, see [Hendrik Vogt answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61461/38080) to that question.