# Double subscript

Tags: accents, subscripts, grouping

I have some macros whose expansion generates something like:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\({T_2}_k\)
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine; technically there's a double subscript, but the braces hide it from TeX.  However, under some circumstances, the macros generate something like:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\({\widetilde T_2}_k\)
\end{document}
```

This generates the error

```
! Double subscript.
l.3 \({\widetilde T_2}_
                       k\)
?
```

If I were generating the text directly, I could just do `\(\widetilde T_{2k}\)` or similar, but that's not an option here.

**Question 1**.  Why does the first document compile, and the second generate an error?

**Question 2**.  Without changing the definitions of the macros, is there any way to make something like

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand\macroa{\widetilde T_2}
\newcommand\macrob[1]{#1_k}
\begin{document}
\(\macrob\macroa\)
\end{document}
```

compile—e.g., by adding braces, as would work if the first definition were instead:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand\macroa{T_2}
\newcommand\macrob[1]{#1_k}
\begin{document}
\(\macrob{{\macroa}}\)
\end{document}
```

?

EDIT:  Now that I realise that this is an error with mathaccents in general rather than just with `\widetilde`, I see that a nice expansion by [@HendrikVogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61461) of an answer by [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32754) does the necessary digging into TeX's internals to see what is going on.  In particular,

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand\macroa{\widetilde T_2}
\newcommand\macrob[1]{#1_k}
\begin{document}
\(\macrob{{{}\macroa}}\)
\end{document}
```

works (although the apparently more natural

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand\macroa{\widetilde T_2}
\newcommand\macrob[1]{#1_k}
\begin{document}
\(\macrob{{}\macroa}\)
\end{document}
```

doesn't).

Comment: Please clarify whether you want `\widetilde` to span just `T` or `T_2`.

Comment: @Mico, I want it to span just `T`.  However, that part is behaving correctly; it's just the double subscript that puzzles me, since I can't see how an accent could change the subscript handling.

Comment: This is known. While I look for the duplicate, use `{{}\widetilde{T}_2}_k`

Comment: @egreg, indeed, once I realised it was a `\mathaccent` issue I spotted your explanation, on which @‍HendrikVogt elaborated.